# Помогие добавить один лист в другой с помощью стримов. Элементы листа при этом подвергаются измененению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, java-stream

Я написал цикл в котором, элементы листа List lines я добавляю в  List wordList.
При этом мне необходимо каждую строку листа сплитнуть по regex "[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+" и добавить как отдельный элемент wordList.

Вот мой цикл:

```
for (String line : lines) {
        wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.toLowerCase().split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+")));
    }
```

помогите пожалуйста написать данное выражение в Stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, например:

```
List<String> wordList = lines.stream()
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.toLowerCase().split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: да не за что, дело 10 секунд